# Eclipse and Gradle classpath causes slow launch

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, classpath, slowdown

OK so this is a bit of strange one.

We have a Gradle multi module project. We use the Gradle Eclipse plugin to generate the eclipse classpath(s).

Gradle version 2.0
Eclipse 4.4 (Kepler)
JDK 1.8.05

The issue is when running Junit tests or launching Java it takes a long time for the test to start running. Over 5 seconds.

I see the following output in the "Progress" window.

```
Launching: Starting virtual machine...
```

I have **NOT** experienced this issue before and other projects work fine (not using gradle generated classpath)

The generated .classpath file looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="build"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/java"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/test/java"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/test/resources"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER" exported="true"/>
    <classpathentry sourcepath="C:/gradlehome/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/1.1.2/decd76e2c461157804473468bbdc6b8eb6d6121b/logback-classic-1.1.2-sources.jar" kind="lib" path="C:/gradlehome/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/1.1.2/b316e9737eea25e9ddd6d88eaeee76878045c6b2/logback-classic-1.1.2.jar" exported="true"/>
    <classpathentry sourcepath="C:/gradlehome/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.7/b5a646b81b899e930f8600c5f45766dd82743d93/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.7-sources.jar" kind="lib" path="C:/gradlehome/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.7/56003dcd0a31deea6391b9e2ef2f2dc90b205a92/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.7.jar" exported="true"/>
    <classpathentry sourcepath="C:/gradlehome/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.guava/guava/17.0/7ca0efbeb87ca845b5d7a0ac9c21a4b7b95f7b28/guava-17.0-sources.jar" kind="lib" path="C:/gradlehome/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.guava/guava/17.0/9c6ef172e8de35fd8d4d8783e4821e57cdef7445/guava-17.0.jar" exported="true"/>
    <classpathentry sourcepath="C:/gradlehome/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.3.2/d2a489573c0ed2c4942b3660decad5d65087b406/commons-lang3-3.3.2-sources.jar" kind="lib" path="C:/gradlehome/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.3.2/90a3822c38ec8c996e84c16a3477ef632cbc87a3/commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar" exported="true"/>
    <classpathentry sourcepath="C:/gradlehome/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/javax.inject/javax.inject/1/a00123f261762a7c5e0ec916a2c7c8298d29c400/javax.inject-1-sources.jar" kind="lib" path="C:/gradlehome/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/javax.inject/javax.inject/1/6975da39a7040257bd51d21a231b76c915872d38/javax.inject-1.jar" exported="true"/>
    <classpathentry sourcepath="C:/gradlehome/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-web/4.0.6.RELEASE/ea420724d884a43e3db4b08d2ca5ff75715ff9bb/spring-web-4.0.6.RELEASE-sources.jar" kind="lib" path="C:/gradlehome/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-web/4.0.6.RELEASE/85ef4b91fcdd86d81e4a9b3e5f006dcb4128e6d/spring-web-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar" exported="true"/>
    <classpathentry sourcepath="C:/gradlehome/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.2.4/a6dc5db8a12928e583bd3f23e72d3ab611ecd58f/gson-2.2.4-sources.jar" kind="lib" path="C:/gradlehome/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.2.4/a60a5e993c98c864010053cb901b7eab25306568/gson-2.2.4.jar" exported="true"/>
    <classpathentry sourcepath="C:/gradlehome/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-library/1.3/47a7ee46628ab7133129cd7cef1e92657bc275e/hamcrest-library-1.3-sources.jar" kind="lib" path="C:/gradlehome/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-library/1.3/4785a3c21320980282f9f33d0d1264a69040538f/hamcrest-library-1.3.jar" exported="true"/>
    <classpathentry sourcepath="C:/gradlehome/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.mockito/mockito-core/1.9.5/46f703fb4266140c544d48a189cb25947eb6333e/mockito-core-1.9.5-sources.jar" kind="lib" path="C:/gradlehome/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.mockito/mockito-core/1.9.5/c3264abeea62c4d2f367e21484fbb40c7e256393/mockito-core-1.9.5.jar" exported="true"/>
    <classpathentry sourcepath="C:/gradlehome/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-test/4.0.6.RELEASE/f0e39db787769d8926a6ae7baed1a1ebb9d6e50a/spring-test-4.0.6.RELEASE-sources.jar" kind="lib" path="C:/gradlehome/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-test/4.0.6.RELEASE/b2f65445f300f1317fe694e6530cce39d7090ff6/spring-test-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar" exported="true"/>
    <classpathentry sourcepath="C:/gradlehome/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/ch.qos.logback/logback-core/1.1.2/502e1c764542fe747896c1dc04f023acfe0e5cbc/logback-core-1.1.2-sources.jar" kind="lib" path="C:/gradlehome/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/ch.qos.logback/logback-core/1.1.2/2d23694879c2c12f125dac5076bdfd5d771cc4cb/logback-core-1.1.2.jar" exported="true"/>
    <classpathentry sourcepath="C:/gradlehome/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-aop/4.0.6.RELEASE/d21d57199535402a4afdb4e9406d6f5276a5b205/spring-aop-4.0.6.RELEASE-sources.jar" kind="lib" path="C:/gradlehome/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-aop/4.0.6.RELEASE/e377760b7692569535573ba9f6e80b4b74869369/spring-aop-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar" exported="true"/>
    <classpathentry sourcepath="C:/gradlehome/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-beans/4.0.6.RELEASE/5e37af2dc3a230912dbb06b45cc2c1d53c2c9abb/spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE-sources.jar" kind="lib" path="C:/gradlehome/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-beans/4.0.6.RELEASE/587879b58acebeb5b0a63c01e822f9b44d9a4c77/spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar" exported="true"/>
    <classpathentry sourcepath="C:/gradlehome/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-context/4.0.6.RELEASE/778949f894ac1ee2d42a8f074a7477540f4d04a/spring-context-4.0.6.RELEASE-sources.jar" kind="lib" path="C:/gradlehome/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-context/4.0.6.RELEASE/3bb3a52edabf9ffe73aa534fb085c816bac28b4d/spring-context-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar" exported="true"/>
    <classpathentry sourcepath="C:/gradlehome/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-core/4.0.6.RELEASE/5b16ad4018f9012ce3917e2e1038d19d2da57285/spring-core-4.0.6.RELEASE-sources.jar" kind="lib" path="C:/gradlehome/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-core/4.0.6.RELEASE/d880beac77d42c5798aa2b632ddd0e4ae47c79ad/spring-core-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar" exported="true"/>
    <classpathentry sourcepath="C:/gradlehome/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/1dc37250fbc78e23a65a67fbbaf71d2e9cbc3c0b/hamcrest-core-1.3-sources.jar" kind="lib" path="C:/gradlehome/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/42a25dc3219429f0e5d060061f71acb49bf010a0/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar" exported="true"/>
    <classpathentry sourcepath="C:/gradlehome/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.objenesis/objenesis/1.0/b10c90e57b7bb985a7b6a704769428fe5c2a732c/objenesis-1.0-sources.jar" kind="lib" path="C:/gradlehome/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.objenesis/objenesis/1.0/9b473564e792c2bdf1449da1f0b1b5bff9805704/objenesis-1.0.jar" exported="true"/>
    <classpathentry sourcepath="C:/gradlehome/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/junit/junit/4.11/28e0ad201304e4a4abf999ca0570b7cffc352c3c/junit-4.11-sources.jar" kind="lib" path="C:/gradlehome/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/junit/junit/4.11/4e031bb61df09069aeb2bffb4019e7a5034a4ee0/junit-4.11.jar" exported="true"/>
    <classpathentry sourcepath="C:/gradlehome/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/4a4b6d692e17846a9f3da036438a7ac491d3c814/aopalliance-1.0-sources.jar" kind="lib" path="C:/gradlehome/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/235ba8b489512805ac13a8f9ea77a1ca5ebe3e8/aopalliance-1.0.jar" exported="true"/>
    <classpathentry sourcepath="C:/gradlehome/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-expression/4.0.6.RELEASE/b86718cc9e7b5f53be187e8e35b44ad2dfd0196b/spring-expression-4.0.6.RELEASE-sources.jar" kind="lib" path="C:/gradlehome/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-expression/4.0.6.RELEASE/5f0a135b8cf290aa244097dc6264ad0989d25c56/spring-expression-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar" exported="true"/>
    <classpathentry sourcepath="C:/gradlehome/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.3/28bb0405fddaf04f15058fbfbe01fe2780d7d3b6/commons-logging-1.1.3-sources.jar" kind="lib" path="C:/gradlehome/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.3/f6f66e966c70a83ffbdb6f17a0919eaf7c8aca7f/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar" exported="true"/>
    <classpathentry sourcepath="C:/gradlehome/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.7/acd62e31cc314266e73eebed0b6dd7ea974a0ed/slf4j-api-1.7.7-sources.jar" kind="lib" path="C:/gradlehome/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.7/2b8019b6249bb05d81d3a3094e468753e2b21311/slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar" exported="true"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="/my-api-core" exported="true"/>
</classpath>
```

If however I copy the libs to a folder inside the project and remove the higlighted line last entry, then the test starts in milliseconds! The last classpath entry is of type "src"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="build"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/java"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/test/java"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/test/resources"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/junit-4.11.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar" />
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/guava-17.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/hamcrest-library-1.3.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/javax.inject-1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.7.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/logback-classic-1.1.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/logback-core-1.1.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/marketplace-api-core-1.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/mockito-core-1.9.5.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/objenesis-1.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/spring-aop-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/spring-context-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/spring-core-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/spring-expression-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/spring-gson-http-message-converter.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/spring-test-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/spring-web-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/gson-2.2.4.jar" exported="true"/>
    **<classpathentry exported="true" kind="src" path="/my-api-core"/>**
</classpath>
```

I cannot workout what is causing the slow launch?

UPDATE: If I create an Ubuntu VM and use the same project with Gradle generated Eclipse classpath, the issue does not arise

Answer (score 1):

Gradle does a terrible job of generating Eclipse config files, as you've seen. I recommend [installing the Gradle IDE features from Spring Tool Suite](https://github.com/spring-projects/eclipse-integration-gradle/blob/master/README.md#installation-instructions) and let it manage your Eclipse build path. With that, you end up with a `.classpath` that does not have absolute paths to each and every dependency. It looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/java"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/resources"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/test/java"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/test/resources"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.7"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.module.container"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.web.container"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.classpathcontainer">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

I really wish the Gradle plugin that generates Eclipse project files was smarter, but from what I read that team doesn't seem interested in the topic.

By the way, it is also recommended to check in the `.project` and `.classpath` and other Eclipse config files into source control, so that every user gets the exact same configuration of the projec(s).

Comment: Tried using STS but the launch is still slow

Comment: Did you configure the project to let STS's Gradle plugin manage the dependencies? The problem is in how the `.classpath` file was generated; you have to wipe out the generated dependencies and let The Gradle plugin manage it for you.

Comment: Yes, it was imported as a Gradle project.

Comment: Hmm, strange. Does the new `.classpath` still contain the absolute path entries (like `C:/gradlehome/caches...`) or only the `org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.classpathcontainer`?

Comment: it does not contain absolute paths. Just the classpath container as above. my colleague is convinced its a windows/anti virus thing. I can't confirm this yet as I cannot disable the virus on the corporate pc (yet!)